# Does shell script run in a single session using paramiko Python?

Tags: python, shell, paramiko

I am executing a shell script using paramiko with python.

My python code:

```
import paramiko
import sys

userPwd = raw_input("Enter the password? ")
print ('You have entered',userPwd)


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('abc.rnd.se', username='user1', 
    password=userPwd)

try:
    channel=ssh.invoke_shell()

    stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('(cd scripts; ./fetchSuite.sh)')


    print (stdout.read())
    print (stderr.read())

except:
    print ('Some exception:',sys.exc_info())
```

Following is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set path=$path /proj/dailytest/bin
tgr v TEST_SUITE > TestSuite
cat TestSuite
```

However, after setting path variable, I am not able to access the custom command i.e. `tgr`. Moreover, when I echo the path variable after setting the path it does not include the latest updated path.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The syntax to add a variable to the program search path is `export PATH="$PATH:/proj/dailytest/bin"`

Comment: I am getting `not a valid identifer` with export

Comment: Make sure you copy-paste the line exactly.